# How Do I give a navigation link in php while using forms

Tags: php, html

If the login code is validated, I should go into the member page otherwise I should say on the same page..I am not sure how to write a navigation link to another page..I have seen couple of answers using headers but I didn't get it.

login.php

```
if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
{
 // If this condition is true I should go into member page
}

else
{
   echo "incorrect password!"; //should stay in the same page
}
form action= "member.php" method="post"
Username: input type="text" name="username"<br/>
Password: input type="password" name="password"<br/>
input type="submit" value="LogIn"><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `header` like this:

```
if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)

{

header("location:member.php");


}
```

If you want a delay in the redirect you can use this:

```
header("Refresh: 5;url=klanten.php");
```

(this will wait 5 seconds before redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved by posting to the same page, login.php

Before any html, check:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword) {
        header("location: member.php");
    }
}
```

*header("location: member.php")* simply redirects to member.php if condition true.
So the form would look something like this:

```
form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
</form>
```